# change JStree icon with material icons

Tags: javascript, materialize, jstree

I can change JStree icon with fontawesome and glyphicon using code like this:

```
<li data-jstree='{"icon":"fa fa-user"}'>
<li data-jstree='{"icon":"glyphicon glyphicon-print"}'>
```

How to use [Material Icons](https://materializecss.com/icons.html)?

I tried

```
<li data-jstree='{"icon":"material-icons add"}'>
```

But doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do it by including this stylesheet:

https://github.com/Angelmmiguel/material_icons/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/material_icons_unicode.css.erb

after I include above file as CSS  I can use code below to use material-icons:

```
<li data-jstree='{"icon":"material-icons add"}'>
```